# Unable to build In unity: "UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 9 errors"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The project runs just fine but I am unable to build it using build settings.

I keep getting this message when trying to build into WebGL. I am using Unity 2020.3.25f1.

Here's the error message:

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 9 errors
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002be] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:190   at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:95
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:189)

I havent tried anything because I do not know what to do in this scenario. I am a beginner, and I still do not know how to do everything.

Comment: You probably have several error items in the console. You'll need to look at each one to find where it tells you what the actual problem is. I find it easier to just open up the editor.log file and read through it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.